# Problema de acentuação mysql, qual agrupamento devo usar?

Tags: php, mysql

estou tendo problemas com acentuação nos meus dados armazenados no mysql já coloquei agrupamento ut8_general_ci, ut8_bin e não funcionou. o que devo fazer?

Comment: Agrupamento não tem nada a ver com **acentuação**, agrupamento serve para ordenação e busca. O Encoding é que define a acentuação.

Comment: aaa sim entendi... então você poderia me ajudar ? oq devo fazer ?

Comment: O ideal é ler as perguntas e respostas postada no quadro amarelo acima, para entender a relação entre as coisas e selecionar o que for mais adequado para o seu caso